# Use unique class to create select event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is using a class possible to create an `addEventListener` trigger? OR to override the select in a form within a loop to dynamically add a unique id from the select form helper.  More accurately, I am using `grouped_collection_select`.

I have a non unique ID in a form that is in a loop which creates many duplicate but unique forms, but the select id's are not unique.  My javascript gets triggered on a select but since the id is not unique, it only triggers on the first select option and nothing happens on the following other form select option changes.

I have the following form:

in short:

```
<form class="edit_shop_product" id="edit_shop_product_3" action="/shop_products/3" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <select class="shop_style_3" name="shop_product[style_id]" id="shop_product_style_id">
    <option value="">Select Style</option>
    <optgroup label="Apparel"><option selected="selected" value="1">Hoodies</option>
    <option value="2">T-Shirts</option>
    <option value="3">Long Sleeves</option></optgroup>
  </select>
</form>
form 2
<form class="edit_shop_product" id="edit_shop_product_4" action="/shop_products/4" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <select class="shop_style_4" name="shop_product[style_id]" id="shop_product_style_id">
    <option value="">Select Style</option>
    <optgroup label="Apparel"><option value="1">Hoodies</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">T-Shirts</option>
    <option value="3">Long Sleeves</option></optgroup>
  </select>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("shop_product_style_id").addEventListener("change", function(){
  window.alert("Alert");
}, false);
</script>
```

(all of the javascript is looped, yes this is not good practice but i want a working system before i learn more javascript and fix it all)

So, since this is done in rails with the `form_for` form helper, the id is automatically generated and is not unique due to multiple forms on one page.  For anyone coming from my Rails tag, is there a way to possibly override the select menu id and apply a unique one based on the loop count, etc.?

This works, although the issue is that the "id" isn't unique but this id is created by rails and can't be unique since that's how the helper operates.

I added a unique class and tried this following code, but this didn't work:

(summary of code):

```
var shop_style_<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>_<%= "#{shop_product.id}" %> = document.getElementByClass("shop_style_<%= "#{shop_product.id}" %>");
  for (let i = 0, i < shop_style_<%= "#{ff.object.print_location.id}" %>_<%= "#{shop_product.id}" %>; i++){
    window.alert("Alert");
    }
  }, false);
};
```

I tried this and similar iterations a few days back but couldn't get anything alike to work.  I found a SO post about attempting to use class as a select listener.  This is supposed to use the class and then iterate over all classes that match and trigger the code within the javascript event.  But I could not hack it.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wfznoept/1/

The shop_product_id's are dynamic and can always change so hard-coding will not work.  Aside form using the class iteration method, is there any other way to accomplish this, maybe by using the form id and class as a combination to create a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"unique class" is pure nonsense. The whole point of classes in HTML is that they are not unique. They describe a shared behaviour or appearance of groups of elements. You're thinking about the problem completely wrong.

Instead think about classes as a way to enhance the behaviour of your elements. You JS should not need to know that its that special woozit on the fuzzits page. Rather it just knows what a woozit acts like.

If you want to handle events without iterating through the element you can create delegated event handlers that take advantage of the fact that events bubble up to the top of the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let t = e.target;
  if (t.matches('select.special')){
    console.log(t.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select class="special">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This example adds an event handler to the document itself which is a good idea if you are using turbolinks since the handler is idempotent.

Keep your JS in the assets pipeline (or webpacker) and out of your views. Using erb interpolation is really a last resort that should not be used if possible. Use data attributes if you need to pass information between your views and javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let t = e.target;
  if (t.matches('button.special')){
    console.log(t.dataset.foo);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="special" data-foo="bar">Click me!</button>
```

This lets you minify, concatenate and distribute your JS through a CDN which is good for performance and avoids making a godawful mess of things. You might as well learn to do it right from the beginning instead of falling into bad habits.